# Java 2D Game - Checking if player touches another sprite

Tags: java, java-2d, 2d-games, game-development

I have a game of a rocket landing game, where the player is the rocket and you must land it safely at the right speed on the landing pad. This was taken from www.gametutorial.net

Its actually for educational purposes and I recently added a still meteor in the game.
When the player hits the meteor (touches) the game is over.

```
if(...) {
    playerRocket.crashed = true;
}
```

My problem is there I need to replace the "..." with the actual condition that "Has the rocket crashed into the meteor?"

Plus the following variables (coordinates, height and width) for use -
[All Integers]:

```
X and Y coordinates: playerRocket.x, playerRocket.y, meteor.x, meteor.y
Height and Width: playerRocket.rocketImgHeight, playerRocket.rocketImgWidth, meteor.meteorImgHeight, meteor.meteorImgWidth
```

Comment: you need to check for 2 points intersection... in other words you need to check whether rocket's x, y fall in metero's x,y or not

Comment: What do you think? Share with us your thoughts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For collision detection in 2D games, you can use rectangles. I'd use a base class called `GObject` and inherit all objects in the game from it.

```
public class GObject
{

    private Rectangle bounds;

    public float x, y, hspeed, vspeed;

    private Image image;

    public GObject(Image img, float startx, float starty)
    {
        image = img;
        x = startx;
        y = starty;
        hspeed = vspeed = 0;
        bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        bounds.x = x;
        bounds.y = y;
        return bounds;
    }

}
```

There's also other methods like `update()` and `render()` but I'm not showing them. So to check for collision between two objects use

```
public boolean checkCollision(GObject obj1, GObject obj2)
{
    return obj1.getBounds().intersects(obj2.getBounds());
}
```

Also, there's a specific site for game related questions. Go to [Game Development Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is the use of a reusable (but non immutable) Rectange an efficiency measure?

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes it is better to use single object instead of creating one for each frame.

Comment: More efficient yes, I'm not sure I'd say better. It can lead to spooky action at a distance unless you're very careful. For example if at a later date someone decides to use that Rectangle to provide some effects (eg an explosion) that persists over several frames then that explosion may jump around as new collisions occure. If it wasn't a Rectangle but something that extended Rectange where it was clear that it was a moving value

Comment: @RichardTingle Explosions have a very simple mechanism. In most cases, we play explosions as animations but they are not objects. They are sometimes but even in the case, the explosion is carried as the change in images or animation in a specific time interval. For other effects, there are particle systems and in 3D, you always use lighting with Pixel and Vertex Shaders.

Comment: Yes, true, thats not really my point. My point is that if you expose an object through a public method and its not obviously something thats going to change and then you change that object internally you can create unknown effects that are a nightmare to diagnose. As per the object orientated approach knowing what the rest of the program does shouldn't be nessissary. If you were in a very performance limited enviroment and this was the main cpu cost then fair enough (or if this method was supposed to return  a changing value) but otherwise I fear premature optimisation

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you hit the object, meaning, if the click coordinates are within the object's `Rectangle`.

```
if( playerRocket.x + playerRocket.width  >= clickX && playerRocket.x <= clickX  &&
    playerRocket.y + playerRocket.height >= clickY && playerRocket.Y <= clickY ) {

    playerRocket.crashed = true;

}
```